# Не совпадает число значений запроса и число результирующих полей

Tags: visual-basic, ms-access

При попытке отправить запрос в базу данных вылетает следующая ошибка: "Не совпадает число значений запроса и число результирующих полей". Как это можно исправить?

```
    Sub catch_to_base()
    Dim fio As String = frm_admin.txt_fio.Text
    Dim all_day As String = frm_admin.txt_all_day.Text
    Dim have_day As String = frm_admin.txt_have_day.Text
    Dim pay_in_day As String = frm_admin.txt_pay_in_day.Text
    Dim pay_for_work As String = "1000"


    Dim Connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=DB_MyFerm.mdb")
    Connection.Open()


    Dim request As String = "insert into [Работники](" & "[ФИО],[Должность],[Рабочих дней],[Дней отработано],[Оплата в день], [Выплатить]) values('" & fio & "' , '" & all_day & "','" & have_day & "','" & pay_in_day & "', '" & pay_for_work & "')"
    Dim command_for_base = New OleDbCommand(request)
    command_for_base.Connection = Connection


    Try
        command_for_base.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("done")
    Catch ex As Exception
        debug_message.show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Connection.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас, в запросе на добавление, количество полей "откуда" и "куда" не совпадают.

насколько я понял должно быть так:

```
Dim sSQL$
sSQL = "insert into [Работники](" & "[ФИО],[Рабочих дней],[Дней отработано],[Оплата в день], [Выплатить]) " & _
    " values('" & fio & "' , '" & all_day & "','" & have_day & "','" & pay_in_day & "', '" & pay_for_work & "')"
```